# Ordering entities on a DB level based on a child entity type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

The relationships look something like this:

```
class EntityA 
{
   public Country DestinationCountry { get; set; }
}

class Country 
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public IList<CountryLocalization> Localizations { get; set; } =
        new List<CountryLocalization>();
}
public class CountryLocalization
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public CountryLocalizationType LocalizationType { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

So every entity A has one DestinationCountry. Every Country has multiple localizations based on the given language
e.g.

Entity A has a destination country which has two translations in two different languages.

Is it possible to order a list of `EntityA`s based on localized country names, by supplying the `LocalizationType`?

```
IQueriable<EntityA> query = query.OrderBy(a => a.Where(b => b.DestinationCountry.Localizations.Where(l => l.LocalizationType == ENG)) ...
```

Comment: EF translates LINQ to SQL. Can you do what you want in SQL? Then EF can do it as well. You wouldn't put a WHERE in ORDER BY though. You'd JOIN the tables, filter by country and *then* order by the localized name. You need to do the same in EF Core

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? In the recent ones you can use [filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) to load only the localized name you want, then sort by it

Comment: Do you want all the translations or just one translation in your result set? Actually, it doesn't matter that much but will change the query.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. SQL basics 101: Tables are SETS, not LISTS - SETS by definition are unordered. A sql server is allowed to return rows in any order it wants UNLESS TOLD TO ORDER THEM. That is IN THE QUERY.

A default sort order would make a lot of sense, but - seems that the EfCore people so far stand on the principle that you ordering in a query is more than enough.

So, no - you can not do that in the mapping definition. You need to put the order into every time you request the entities.

Sad, if you ask me - I had an OR mapper 15 years ago that allowed that. But hey, remember. EfCore is so modern. Maybe one day they get to that.

Comment: *SQL*, the language, has no default sort order. PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, are all free to return rows in the cheapest way possible if no ORDER BY is include.  If the ORM you had 15 years ago had a default order, it emitted an ORDER BY behind your back, a *VERY* bad idea if the order field isn't indexed or the table contains a lot of data. Or, the queries were simple enough that the data came back in storage order. A hash join operation would change the order of results for example. Parallelization certainly would

Comment: Oh, I never said it did not - but when writign an ORM then you realize that in many cases the data HAS a default sort order. Invoice - InvoiceItem, ther is a number field on InvoiceItem as the lines are ordered. So yes, ordering on that level makes a lot of sense, if the user has not defined a sort order. Same, as example, in odata - many items have logical internal ordering. Never said it was not the ORM - but it was a feature beloved.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in many ways, one of them:

```
var query  = from a in context.EntityA.Include(r=> r.DestinationCountry)
join loc in context.CountryLocalization on
 new { CountryCode = a.DestinationCountry.CountryCode, LocalizationType = "ENG"}
 equals  new { loc.CountryCode, loc. LocalizationType }
order by lo.CountryName
select new { A =a, lo.CountryName };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by `Single` or `First` operators:

```cs
var query = query
    .OrderBy(a => a.DestinationCountry.Localizations
        .Where(l => l.LocalizationType == "ENG")
        .Select(l => l.CountryName).Single()
    );
```

Or by `Join`, which produces better SQL:

```cs
var query = 
    from a in query
    from l in a.DestinationCountry.Localizations.Where(l => l.LocalizationType == "ENG")
    orderby l.CountryName
    select a;
```

If you want to do that automatically, it would require to Expression Tree interception by registering own `IQueryExpressionInterceptor` and adding additional `OrderBy` into Expression Tree.